# Objective-C: int can´t be NAN?

Tags: objective-c, ios, int, double, nan

It seems that a int in Objective-C can't be NAN.
This comparision returns false.

```
int i = NAN;
NSLog(@"isNan: %@", (isnan(i)) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Is there any way to set an int to NAN, or do i have to use a double?

```
double d = NAN;
NSLog(@"isNan: %@", (isnan(d)) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

With a double it works.

Comment: Objective-C is not alone in that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NaN` is a value that is specific to the way that floating point numbers (`float` and `double` in C) are represented internally (IEEE 754). Is is not available for integer data types, as they may be represented in a completely different manner.

As a workaround, you may see people use a separate boolean flag to indicate if a value is valid, or the extreme values `INT_MIN`/`INT_MAX`. Although, nether of these is as good as `NaN` for ensuring valid values.

Answer (score 3):

NAN is a floating point value from IEEE 754 standard (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Integer_NaN):

> Most fixed sized integer formats do not have any way of explicitly indicating invalid data.